# O que são views em SQL? Quais vantagens e desvantagens em utilizar?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, terminologia, sql-view

Pelas pesquisas tive o conhecimento que as *views* em SQL, são como tabelas virtuais resultados de pesquisas armazenadas de acesso frequente.

A [W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp) define essencialmente como tabela virtual.

Há que diga que *views* são pesquisas armazenadas.

#### Dúvidas:

1. O que são *views*?
2. Quais vantagens e desvantagens em utilizar?
3. Assumindo que são tabelas virtuais, eu gostaria de saber se elas são sempre carregadas na altura em que o servidor de base de dados arranca? E sempre que alguma das tabelas envolvidas/relacionadas a esta *view* sofrer uma atualização a *view* sofre de igual modo?
4. Se for apenas uma consulta, que diferença terá com *StoredProcedure*?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

View é um resultado originado de uma consulta pré-definida. Essencialmente é um metadado que mapeia uma *query* para outra, por isto pode ser considerado como uma tabela virtual. Como o próprio nome diz, ela representa uma **visão** de dados e não contém dados. Com ela você tem a ilusão que está vendo uma tabela que não existe. Claro que o que você vê nesta tabela existe de outra forma no banco. Veja [mais detalhes na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)).

Pode ajudar entender saber que elas também são chamadas de *named queries* ou *stored queries*. Não confundir *query* (consulta) com resultado. Ela é a *query* mesmo. É basicamente um texto de um `SELECT`. Pense que ela é uma *query* que você armazena em uma variável e ao invés de escrever toda a *query* de novo sempre que for necessária usa a variável. Claro que isto é uma grande simplificação para facilitar o entendimento, o funcionamento real é pouco mais complexo que isto mas não é importante aqui.

Elas não são carregadas, elas são geradas sempre que forem necessárias.

A não ser que a *view* seja [materializada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Materialized_view), aí você terá tabelas reais representando essas *views*. Mas a carga delas ocorrerão conforme a necessidade e otimizações do banco de dados. Só neste tipo de *view* é que os dados são atualizados quando as tabelas reais sofrem atualizações ([resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138033/101)).

Mas é importante notar que mesmo em uma *view* não materializada existe a ilusão de que uma atualização da tabela real envolvida reflita na *view*, afinal a *view* é gerada no momento que ela é necessária. Essas tabelas virtuais são dinâmicas, elas só existem no momento em que você precisa delas. Somente a *query* para sua geração é pré-definida. Se um dado for atualizado logo em seguida uma *view* for acessada, essa atualização não será considerada neste momento, somente na próxima vez que a *view* for usada.

É bom entender que essa "tabela virtual" que é criada, não é bem uma tabela física criada em memória com todos os dados que você precisa. A *view* é apenas uma forma de traduzir uma *query* para outra *query* mais complexa. Mas uma otimização pode acabar tornando sim uma *view* comum em tabela física. Claro isto depende da implementação do DB.

Uma *view* é muito usada para ajudar dar entendimento do projeto lógico do banco de dados.

#### Exemplo:

Aqui vemos uma *view* criada para facilitar o acesso aos funcionários que são de Seattle que. Desta forma é possível acessar as informações mais importantes destes funcionários de forma consolidada em uma "tabela virtual" chamada `SeattleOnly`. Fazendo com que desta forma possuam todas as vantagens citadas abaixo.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.SeattleOnly
AS
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, e.JobTitle, a.City, sp.StateProvinceCode
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN Person.Person p
ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress bea 
    ON bea.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID 
    INNER JOIN Person.Address a 
    ON a.AddressID = bea.AddressID
    INNER JOIN Person.StateProvince sp 
    ON sp.StateProvinceID = a.StateProvinceID
WHERE a.City = 'Seattle'
```

Retirado do [exemplo usando o banco AdventureWorks da Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15).

Exemplo de uso:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SeattleOnly WHERE LastName = 'Willians';
```

Note que retornará 4 colunas. No fundo isto é o mesmo que escrever:

```
SELECT p.LastName, p.FirstName, e.JobTitle, a.City, sp.StateProvinceCode
FROM HumanResources.Employee e
INNER JOIN Person.Person p
ON p.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID
    INNER JOIN Person.BusinessEntityAddress bea 
    ON bea.BusinessEntityID = e.BusinessEntityID 
    INNER JOIN Person.Address a 
    ON a.AddressID = bea.AddressID
    INNER JOIN Person.StateProvince sp 
    ON sp.StateProvinceID = a.StateProvinceID
WHERE a.City = 'Seattle' AND p.LastName = 'Willians'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Other/View.sql)

## Vantagens

- Você pode usar este resultado em outras consultas diminuindo a complexidade, afinal você fará referência a uma tabela virtual montada fora desta consulta. De uma certa forma podemos considerar como *syntax sugar* para uma *query*. Você tem uma visão mais limitada dos dados sem grandes preocupações.
- Estas **consultas** pré-definidas ficam armazenadas e você não precisa lembrar de como criá-las. Não confundir com resultados.
- Como o próprio nome ajuda identificar elas permitem criar uma visão mais lógica para um humano entender a modelagem.
- Facilita a troca do modelo físico sem o perigo de quebrar *queries* existentes.
- Eventualmente o banco de dados **pode** fazer algumas otimizações por já ter conhecimento das *queries* utilizadas nas *views*. Mas normalmente isto depende até mais das estatísticas coletadas.
- Você pode colocar permissões na *view*, ou seja, você pode proibir acesso à tabelas em seu estado bruto, mas em uma certa condição o usuário pode ter acesso à informação da forma como você definiu na *view*. Você controla melhor o que e como o usuário pode acessar a informação. Funciona como um *firewall*.
- Regras de negócio podem ser adotadas nas *views*. A maneira como você vai acessar os dados está pré-definida. Isto é útil para formatar dados, ajudar ferramentas externas e facilitar o acesso via APIs. Pense em [colunas computadas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_column). Você pode usá-las como um *proxy* e realizar operações sempre que os dados sejam acessados.
- Podem facilitar o acesso em base legada, tornando migrações e transições indolores.
- Se a *view* for materializada pode ter ganho de performance para o acesso aos dados já "consolidados".

## Desvantagens

- Esconde uma complexidade da *query* podendo enganar o desenvolvedor quanto à performance necessária para acessar determinada informação. E pode ser pior quando *views* usam outras *views*. Em alguns casos você pode estar fazendo consultas desnecessárias sem saber de forma muito intensiva.
- Cria uma camada extra. Mais objetos para administrar. Algumas pessoas consideram isto um aumento de complexidade. Uma outra forma de ver isto é que uma *view* pode ser mal usada.
- Pode limitar exageradamente o que o usuário pode acessar impedindo certas tarefas.
- Se a *view* for materializada fará com que alterações nas tabelas reais envolvidas sejam mais lentas, afinal são mais tabelas para atualizar. Este tipo de *view* funciona de forma semelhante a um [gatilho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger).

Existem alguns detalhes técnicos que podem trazer problemas mas acho que não é relevante para esta pergunta.

## Diferença para *Stored Procedure*

Acho que já começa entrar em outra questão. Mas resumindo uma *Stored Procedure* permite **mais flexibilidade** para criar algoritmos mais complexos mas ela não cria uma tabela virtual. Como você vai lidar com isto para expor os dados e chamar uma *Sproc* é um problema do programador dela ou da *query* que vai usá-la.

Ainda bem que não perguntou a diferença para usar uma tabela temporária, aí ficaria amplo de vez :)

Comment: Grato @bigown. Deste uma olhada no link do W3C? :)

Comment: Não, até porque você não colocou um link para a [W3C](http://www.w3.org/). Você colocou para a W3Schools que eu sempre ignoro :D

Comment: Alguém (@bigown) precisa me dizer porquê ignoram o W3Schools?

Comment: Porque eles falam muita bobagem lá, é uma referência que deseduca os desenvolvedores :)

Comment: rsrsrsrs. @bigown, se percebi bem, na verdade as "tabelas virtuais" são geradas sempre que a "view" (que an verdade é uma query armazenada) for invocada? A única diferença esta na organização das consultas, ou seja, deste jeito podemos escrever uma unica vez e reutilizar várias certo? Se assim for, tabelas virtuais existem sempre que se fizer uma consulta.

Comment: É basicamente isto. Vou até editar e colocar mais um detalhe.

Comment: Valeu @bigown. Agora quanto aos detalhes técnicos, terei de fazer outra questão ou podes dar mesmo já aqui? :D. Outra dúvida que fica é quanto as `StoredProcedure`, se por exemplo eu copiar os conteúdo de uma e executar como se tivesse executando uma consulta qualquer ele funcionaria lindamente, ou o `SGDB` interpreta de forma diferente quando se trata de uma `StoredProcedure`?

Comment: São coisa como você deletar a tabela que a *view* usa e ela ficar inválida, não é uma desvantagem, é algo que tem que ser observado, tem que se preocupar com o uso correto. Sobre *Sprocs* eu acho que já não cabe nesta pergunta. Mas o que perguntou, funciona. *Sprocs* aceita tudo o que o SQL aceita.

Comment: @bigown devia dar para por estrelinha no seu comentário do W3Schools que se aproveitaram da sigla do W3C para parecerem sérios.

Answer (score 4):

Vou dar um exemplo e fazer as considerações:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE t (qty INT, price INT);
mysql> INSERT INTO t VALUES(3, 50);
mysql> CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT qty, price, qty*price AS value FROM t;
mysql> SELECT * FROM v;
```

Temos umas tabela com **preço** e **quantidade** e quero saber o tal do "**valor total**" já vi muita gente me falando que colocar o valor total na tabela é justificável através da "**[desnormalização](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desnormaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o)**", mas veja que não necessário e não recomendado colocar dados em uma tabela que você pode obte-los através de calculos, então a **view** pode entrar nesse caso para que o calculo seja obtido sem ele existir em tabela alguma, porque ele esta em uma view que podemos definir como uma consulta pré-definida ao B.D. ou uma tabela virtual.

Neste exemplo já esta respondido o item **1** e **2**. Ref. ao **3** só é desvantagem se for mal utilizado, e a vantagem já esta no exemplo também.

> E sempre que alguma das tabelas envolvidas/relacionadas a esta view sofrer uma atualização a view sofre de igual modo?

- Sim pois a view é uma consulta a tabelas, se dados mudam o resultado da view também muda, ref. a ser carregadas quando o banco inicia, creio que isso pode depender do SGBD.

Eu vejo que a view é comumente usada por DBA's para delimitar acesso, o DBA faz a regra do que determinado programa pode visualizar do seu banco usando a view e dando acesso ao programa apenas nessa parte onde lhe é permitido através dos privilégios, e as **Stored Procedure** são usadas mais para quando os dados precisam ser tratados de forma mais complexa.