# Numa estrutura MVC, podemos criar um model que representa uma View (SQL)?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mvc, modelo-relacional

Estava discutindo com um amigo meu sobre o uso de *views* (digo as do MySQL, e não a do *pattern* MVC).

Daí surgiu uma dúvida no seguinte sentido: Um *Model* serve pra representar uma estrutura de dados, podendo-se ler e escrever dados numa tabela através dele. 
Sendo assim, eu poderia utilizar, numa estrutura MVC, um *model* que represente uma *view* SQL (assim que geralmente ele representa uma tabela)?

Por exemplo, se eu tenho uma *view* no MySQL, eu posso representar a mesma através de um *model* em um *framework*, como CakePHP, ou Laravel, ou Django?

Digo isso pois os *models* geralmente possuem métodos para gravação de dados. E as *views* são apenas formas de visualizar dados.

Se eu fizesse um *model* representando uma SQL *view*, poderia estar violando o princípio do *model*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em teoria, pode. [*Views* no MySQL podem inserir e atualizar registros](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html). Só não podem excluir registros das tabelas envolvidas.

Claro que a montagem do padrão MVC em cima de uma *View* em SQL precisa ser mais criteriosa. Algumas operações terão limitações e você terá que trabalhá-las.

O ideal ainda é construir *Models* em cima de tabelas, com a aplicação tendo domínio pleno sobre o banco de dados.

Comment: Pode inserir, atualizar, mas não pode deletar. Que incrível isso! vai saber como é tratado esses dados internamente! Sobre o fato de a aplicação ter domínio, você está querendo dizer no sentido de: _Se já tenho o model pra trabalhar com os dados, não preciso de uma sql view_?

Comment: Em teoria não precisa porque a aplicação se encarrega de abstrair os dados pra você. O que eu considero válido para uso de *Views* é o conceito de [*Views Materializadas*](http://www.fromdual.ch/mysql-materialized-views), em que se consolida a projeção de uma *View* em cima de dados físicos. Ou seja, a *View* passa a existir fisicamente.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode colocar o que quiser um um *model*. Ele representa dados organizados de tal forma que pode ser utilizado pelo *controller* para produzir *views*.

É comum que os modelos representem tabelas de um banco de dados. Neste caso é comum que o modelo se encarregue de leitura e escrita no banco de dados. Mas isto não é um requisito.

Uma [*view* do SQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35413/101) representa dados existentes no banco de dados, simulando o que existiria em uma tabela física. Ela funciona como uma tabela lógica.

Então nada impede que ela seja usada como base para o modelo, desde que a lógica para acesso à *view* esteja adequada.

Obviamente que só poderá alterar dados através da *view* se o [banco de dados tiver esta capacidade](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html), o que não é comum em alguns sistemas. E mesmo onde é possível, existem limitações.

Fora isto pode haver alguma limitação imposta pelos *frameworks* citados.

Eu fiz uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165925/101) que fala mais sobre isto porque é algo confuso e no fundo é opinião, inclusive a mesma pessoa tem opinião diferente dependo do momento.

Comment: Pelo menos no laravel, eu teria como criar uma espécie de "trava" onde nenhum dado poderia ser inserido. Isso faria ser compreensível a todos que se trata de uma `sql view`