# Qual a diferença entre View e Materialized View?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, terminologia, sql-view

Segundo a documentação da Oracle, uma **[Materialized View](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm)** é um objeto de banco de dados que contém os resultados de uma consulta e uma **[View](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8004.htm)** é uma tabela lógica baseada em uma ou mais tabelas ou vistas e não contém dados em si.

Ok, a documentação fala sobre o que é cada uma e possui até mais detalhes. Mas, para leigos, qual é realmente a diferença entre as duas? Existem diferença entre desempenho e custos processuais do banco de dados?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Boa parte desta pergunta já está respondida de forma mais completa em [O que são views em SQL? Quais vantagens e desvantagens em utilizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35413/101) (tem exemplo de uso lá e vantagens e desvantagens do uso da *view*)

## *View*

A *view* é uma consulta (chega ser um código SQL mesmo) simples armazenada no banco de dados que cria uma ilusão de ser uma tabela, e pode ser usada em diversas operações para:

- simplificar as *queries* e facilitar o acesso à determinadas informações
- conformar melhor com o modelo lógico
- permitir controlar melhor o acesso aos dados para determinados usuários

  Pode-se criar uma *view* com determinadas colunas e dar permissão de acesso a um usuário ou grupo para essa *view*, não para a tabela física, aí ele só terá acesso a esses dados.

Todo conjunto de dados da *view* é gerado no momento que é solicitado (se nenhuma otimização for feita pelo banco de dados). E esse é o único custo, que nem pode ser considerado exatamente de extra porque se está usando ela, provavelmente precisaria fazer isto de qualquer jeito.

## *Materialized view*

Esta é uma *view* que cria uma tabela auxiliar para armazenar os dados da *query* estabelecida pela *view*. Assim o banco de dados cria uma espécie de gatilho automático para que toda atualização de dados nas colunas envolvidas atualize também a visão materializada (tabela auxiliar), permitindo assim o acesso direto aos dados sem maiores processamentos em uma consulta.

- Com ela você ganha performance de acesso aos dados, mas passa ter um custo maior de atualização dos dados. Precisa analisar o que é mais interessante em cada caso. Então esta é uma otimização de acesso.
- Ela, obviamente, ocupa espaço em "disco".

Essas são as principais vantagens e desvantagens dela sobre a *view* normal.

Fora o fato de haver armazenamento dos dados, elas funcionam de forma essencialmente idênticas (pode variam um pouco dependendo do fornecedor de banco de dados).

É possível simular uma *materialized view* em todo banco de dados que tenha um mecanismo de *trigger*.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No postgres você atualiza uma materialized view através do comando REFRESH, não há um gatilho automático para atualização da view materializada, então, não são todos os bancos que implementam este gatilho automático. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html

Comment: @MurilloHenrique é verdade, é que o contexto da pergunta é mais em cima do Oracle mesmo.

Answer (score 11):

Basicamente, a *View* materializada é um objeto de dados à parte, enquanto que a *View* tradicional é uma projeção em cima de outros objetos de dados, calculada a partir do momento que alguma operação de seleção é feita sobre ela.

Em termos de desempenho, a *View* materializada é normalmente superior a uma *View* tradicional porque não existem os custos de *joins*, percurso de índices, parametrizações e outros fatores, porque o resultado da execução foi exatamente **materializado** em um objeto de dados com colunas, dados e estatísticas próprias.