# Como criar um index para duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo no SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, índices

Tenho quase certeza que não há como fazer mas, vamos lá...

Tenho o seguinte cenário: (incluí somente os campos fundamentais para brevidade)

```
 - Tabela Venda: 
   - id: int;
   - cliente_id: int;
   - cliente_tipo: char(1);
 - Tabela PessoaFisica:
   - id: int;
   - nome: varchar(100);
   - uf: char(2);
 - Tabela PessoaJuridica:
   - id: int;
   - razao_social: varchar(100);
   - uf: char(2);
```

Não criei o banco e sou obrigado a trabalhar com o mesmo nessa forma.

Minha situação é: em determinados casos, tenho que fazer consultas onde eu dependo da venda para chegar até o meu cliente e, com base no estado onde o mesmo se encontra, determinar uma regra de trabalho para o mesmo.

O problema é que se minha *query* ficar muito complexa e em muitos níveis de ação percebo que está cada vez mais lento a consulta. Então pensei nos índices.

O problema é que para tal, preciso vincular um índice na tabela venda que possa se relacionar tanto a `PessoaFisica` quanto para `PessoaJuridica`. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível. Tem banco de dados que é até tem como, mas o SQL Server não consegue, nem com funções ou colunas computadas.

Uma forma é criar um mecanismo onde sempre traga o dado da outra tabela para a que precisa o índice e usar as duas colunas ali. É a desnormalização forçada para atender uma demanda. É preciso cuidado para não perder a consistência.

Precisa pensar se tem alguma outra forma de fazer isto. Quem sabe criar uma [*view*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138033/101) possa ajudar.

Comment: Já esperava esse tipo de resposta, tanto que depois de dias brigando com o DBA ele mesmo entendeu o nível da burrada... mas muito obrigado mesmo assim...