# Qual diferença entre uma View e uma Stored Procedure em SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures

Tenho-me deparado com Views em SQL e também com stored procedures.
Gostaria de entender melhor, qual a diferença entre uma view e a uma stored procedure e quais as suas finalidades?

Seria possivel fornecer 1 caso prático para cada situação?

Comment: TRelacionada ou dup também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164400/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138033/101

Comment: obrigado @Maniero. não tinha encontrado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma `view` é tratada "como se fosse" uma tabela pelo banco de dados.
Basicamente é um `select` salvo no banco.  É utilizada para salvar uma visualização (`select`) no banco.

Já `stored procedure` como o nome diz, é uma sequência de procedimentos, que pode incluir comandos "DML" como `select`, `update` e `insert` ou "DDL", como `create table` por exemplo. Uma *stored procedure* pode ou não retornar dados.

Seu uso é muito mais amplo que uma `view`, pois permite executar uma infinidade de comandos da linguagem `SQL`.
Do ponto de vista de um `select`, seu comportamento é similar: mantém um consulta salva, otimizando a performance, mas a diferença, em se pensando simplesmente em `select`, é que uma *stored procedure*  permite a passagem de parâmetros, logo pode executar uma consulta filtrada (`where` por exemplo), já uma `view` não aceita parâmetros.

Answer (score 4):

### `VIEWS`

Uma `VIEW` é, basicamente, uma consulta [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), onde construímos uma `query`, normalmente mais complexa do que um simples `SELECT`, e que depois podemos utilizar como se fosse uma tabela.

**Exemplo**

```
CREATE VIEW V_Exemplo
AS
    SELECT      T1.Id
            ,   T1.Data
            ,   T2.Texto
    FROM        T1
    INNER JOIN  T2 ON T2.IdT1 = T1.Id
```

O exemplo acima vai criar uma VIEW juntando a tabela `T1` e `T2` e devolvendo resultados das colunas `Id` e `Data` da `T1` e `Texto` da `T2`.

As `VIEWS` devem ser criadas quando uma consulta específica é evocada múltiplas vezes, e para executar basta:

```
SELECT * FROM V_Exemplo
```

Ao invés de voltarmos a executar a mesma `query`, que pode ser complicado gerir.

**Atenção**, as `VIEWS` não permitem o uso de parâmetros, logo não conseguiremos restringir a consulta da mesma forma que, digamos, numa `Stored Procedure`.

---

### `Stored Procedure`

Uma `Stored Procedure` é, basicamente, um método parametrizável onde podemos incluir lógica.

É bem mais flexível que a `VIEW`, não só porque permite o uso de parâmetros de entrada mas também porque lá podemos executar [praticamente] tudo.

Vamos imaginar que na consulta que colocámos acima precisávamos de filtrar a data para restringir resultados:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Exemplo (IN Data DATETIME)
BEGIN
    SELECT      T1.Id
            ,   T1.Data
            ,   T2.Texto
    FROM        T1
    INNER JOIN  T2 ON T2.IdT1 = T1.Id
    WHERE       T1.Data >= Data
END //
DELIMITER
```

Neste caso já conseguimos obter, por exemplo, apenas 1.000 resultados de uma tabela com 1.000.000, algo que não é possível apenas com a `VIEW`.

As `VIEWS` e as `SPs` têm implementações completamente diferentes, e devem ser utilizadas consoante o cenário em causa.

As indicações que dei são, de certa forma, simplistas, mas espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

View é uma consulta armazenada no seu banco de dados, quanto a stored procedure é um procedimento armazenado. 
Na View, vc tem uma consulta que retorna algum resultado. Já a stored procedure ela contem um processo, que pode ser start de backup, ponteiros, while's e, dependendo da configuração, e do SGBD, funções e processos do proprio sistema operacional.

Comment: então uma view pode ser por exemplo uma query que eu tenho já pré feita pra ser executada?

Comment: Exatamente. Ex: View: `CREATE VIEW ´accounts_v_members_males´ AS SELECT ´membership_number´,´full_names´,´gender´ FROM ´members´ where ´gender´ = ´M´ ;` Ex: Procedure `DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM products;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;`

Comment: entendi. muito obrigado.