# Qual a maneira correta de ter campos definidos por usuários em um banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem

Se o problema a ser resolvido permite que os usuários armazenem dados não previstos no banco de dados, além dos previstos, e que eles recuperem esses dados e até pesquisem sobre eles, em linhas gerais, o que teria que ser pensado para isso funcionar adequadamente?

Considere que o banco de dados funciona melhor no todo como relacional, um NoSQL não é vantagem aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No passado tinha bem pouca saída, hoje tem opções.

Claro que sempre tem que ser dito que precisa analisar o problema de forma mais específica.

Entendo que o DB tem um modelo estável e uma ou outra tabela deve ter campos definidos pelo usuário.

Não fará muita diferença se for só uma tabela, as soluções seriam as mesmas, embora pode pender mais para um lado ou outro dependendo do uso.

Entendo que os campos serão definidos com chave e valor, ou seja, além do dado em si tem um metadado que diz o que é aquele dado. Em alguns casos pode ter vários metadados, e pode começar quase reproduzir as características do gerenciados do banco de dados. Dá para fazer com tudo isso, mas vai ficando mais complicado, pode precisar realmente quase reproduzir o que o que SGDBR faz. Pode ter além do nome, o tipo, tamanho, restrições e outras informações relevantes que podem ser úteis.

## Solução universal

Pode ser útil usar o padrão [*Entity Key-Value*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138621/101), onde pode ter uma (com um campo dizendo a que tabela ele pertence, se necessário) ou mais tabelas com a chave o valor e talvez ouros metadados. Então pode armazenar qualquer cosia que o usuário quiser, poderá fazer restrições se criar o mecanismo adequado, e poderá pesquisar nos dados e recuperá-los se também tiver uma lógica para lidar com isso. Dá até para criar uma [*view*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138033/101) para abstrair isso da aplicação, e com alguma sofisticação (criando funções) dá um bom resultado, mas não sei se não é mais fácil e mais poderoso tratar na aplicação.

Note que além da chave e valor deve ter também um identificador de qual é a linha a que o dado específico pertence. Então além do `id` da sua própria linha, deve ter pelo menos 3 campos, 4 se lidar com várias tabelas e colocar tudo em uma "tabela deus" (não costuma ser recomendado, especialmente para grandes volumes, mas tem casos que é melhor assim).

## Solução moderna

Outra solução é usar um ou mais campos em cada tabela que seja dona dos campos definidos e gravar tudo como JSON. É possível que o próprio banco de dados já tenha mecanismos que ajudam pesquisar e recuperar dados neles.

O sistema de metadados, se tiver, pode ser junto, ou pode ser separado do dado, depende da necessidade. Junto dá mais flexibilidade e eficiência na maioria dos casos, mas em alguns pode ser melhor tê-los separado, como um banco de dados faz.

Se o gerenciador que está usando não tem facilidade para JSON então pode não ser uma boa ideia.

## Outras soluções

Se tiver alguma restrição, ou algum padrão específico de como esses campos podem ser criados, então pode haver outras soluções, mas aí só com o problema concreto para avaliar.

Tem casos que pode funcionar ter colunas pré-definidas opcionais no lugar de serem definidas pelo usuário, especialmente em alguns DBs que podem otimizar isso, pode ser bem mais fácil e barato, mesmo tendo algum desperdício. Note que aí o problema não é bem o que está na pergunta, só estou considerando porque a pergunta pode partir de uma premissa errada.

## O que não funciona

- Pode ser que tenha alguma exceção, mas quase sempre não funcionará criar campos reais no banco de ados. Em geral isso é possível porque o banco de dados pode receber qualquer comando SQL, até mesmo para manipular as tabelas. Mas a tabela ficará uma bagunça, não haverá ganho na maioria das situações, e pode ficar bem complicado acessar esses dados para pesquisa ou recuperação.
- Pode ter exceção, mas criar campos e deixar lá para uso também não costuma funcionar, especialmente se eles podem ser de vários tipos. Teria que ser um problema simples demais, mal dá para dizer que é um padrão de *user defined fields* se ele funcionar. É muito desperdício e a complicação de realizar é a mesma ou pior das boas soluções.

## Problemas gerais

- Lembre-se que não poderá indexar individualmente os campos de forma específica, então a performance pode não ser tão boa. Dá para indexar o conjunto, mas os índices ficarão grandes porque a chave deles tem muito dado e o conjunto geral será bem maior, então haverá pouco otimização e acesso em memória. Isso tende funcionar com bases de dados menores e com pouca concorrência de acesso, ainda que funcione em qualquer uma. Pode ser que precise de um mecanismo extra de indexação além do banco de dados oferece. O problema provavelmente já pediria isso.
- Sem um mecanismo bem sofisticado para armazenar os dados, ou até recuperar, não será algo robusto e poderá dar muitos erros. Se usar tipos de dados e restrições terá uma dificuldade, e se usar uma técnica jocosamente chamade de *stringly typed* terá que avaliar cada acesso. ao dado.
- Recursos mais avançados do banco de dados ficarão indisponíveis para esses campos, por exemplo chave estrangeira, ainda que dê para simular de forma pouco vantajosa e fácil.

## Em resumo

Só para você achar que foi o ChatGPT que escreveu isso (vai sonhando :)).

Este não é um problema simples de resolver e não tem solução tão boa porque ele subverte o que o banco de dados faz bem, mas onde precisa talvez não precise tanto do que ele é capaz. A solução moderna tende ser mais adequada quando está disponível, mas algum requisito pode fazer com que ele não encaixe bem.

[Exemplo real](https://backchannel.org/blog/friendfeed-schemaless-mysql).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O bom do JSON também que facilmente pode ter um segundo campo complementar para persistir um JSON schema e assim conseguir validar os dados mesmo que dinâmicos; além de que, se realmente necessário a indexação, um simples `generated column` como `stored`, indexada e em conjunto com a `json_extract` já resolveria.

Comment: Em Db que suporta isso.

Comment: Não entendi uma coisa, qual a diferença entre "ter colunas pré-definidas" e "criar campos e deixar lá para uso", a primeira é uma possível boa solução, a segunda é uma provável má solução, mas me parece a mesma coisa, colunas que podem ser nulas. Entendi algo errado?

Comment: @Costamilam Está certo, depende do caso. Não deixa de ser uma solução, mas não costuma funcionar bem, dei a opção, mas mostro que não é boa, a não ser que seja no caso específico, ou seja a única opção por alguma razão.