# Qual é a diferença entre usar uma view ou um sinônimo para uma tabela?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-view

Em um banco de dados que permite ambos, por que devemos usar um

```
CREATE VIEW Users AS SELECT * FROM Identity.dbo.Users
```

ou um

```
CREATE SYNONYM Users FOR Identity.dbo.Users
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No exemplo específico não tem porque criar uma *view*. O objetivo do sinônimo é justamente para dar um outro nome para um objeto do banco de dados, seja uma tabela ou outra coisa.

De forma geral, se quer dar um apelido para um objeto que não seja uma tabela, a *view* não é aceita.

Se a *view* é para pegar a tabela toda sem mudar nome e está só dando um outro nome, não tem porque usá-la, o `SYNONYM` é mais adequado. Ele é até mais poderoso porque permite utilizar algo além da base de dados atual.

A *view* só funciona com tabelas, tem influência na otimização do acesso, e é muito mais flexível para pegar só o que deseja. Essa flexibilidade é tudo o que pode ser feito em um `SELECT`.

A tal ponto que pode usar para criar uma forma de acesso mais restrita de acordo com autorização que o usuário possui, e manter versões de acesso baseados em um modelo antigo ou futuro, ajudando manter compatibilidade entre versões da base de dados ou dar uma forma mais específica para uma operação como um relatório por exemplo. Isso só é possível porque é possível filtrar colunas e linhas que deseja, além de adicionar colunas virtuais e até linhas se usar alguns recursos como `JOIN` ou outras formas que usam outras fontes.

[Mais sobre `VIEW`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138033/101).

Comment: Exemplo 1 de uso de synonym , owner xpto usado por outras partes do sistema ,um public synonym permite que a tabela abc seja refenciada sem precisar de qualificação select * from abc no lugar de selecf * from xpto.abc , e exemplo 2 a tabela bolacha da equipe paulista provoca protestos da equipe carioca , cria-se o synonym biscoito e todos ficam felizes ... :)