# Query Table versus View Table: Qual é a melhor prática?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, hsqldb

Qual é a melhor prática para consultas em um `banco de dados`, realizar uma query direto na `table` ou em uma `view` da mesma? Quais as vantagens e desvantagens entre as mesmas?

Comment: realizar uma query direto na table?  você que dizer direto no banco? ou uma consulta com a própria tabela? tipo select * from tabela;

Comment: Isso, eu quis dizer se é melhor/correto fazer uma consulta direto em uma tabela (select * from tabela) ou senão criar uma `view` com alguns campos apenas e fazer a mesma consulta (select * from view). Qual dessas opções seria o recomendado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As views são, a grosso modo, um resumo para alguma query que precisará usar em diferentes scripts. Isso facilita na manutenção, por exemplo, quando precisar modificar algo, apenas modificaria na view ao invés de mecher em todos os scripts da aplicação que utilizam a mesma query.

Se ficou boiando, vamos a um exemplo prático:

```
SELECT firula FROM tabela_algo
WHERE foo LIKE '%blah';
```

Essa é uma query SQL que você usa em diversos scripts do sistema

Na página **consulta_firula.hph** vc tem uma consulta que invoca essa query

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM tabela_qualquer WHERE id = 5 AND firula NOT IN (SELECT firula FROM tabela_algo
    WHERE foo LIKE '%blah')
```

Até aqui ok. Não há necessidade de criar uma view.

Mas suponha que utilize a mesma query em outra página, **outra_pagina.hph**

```
SELECT x, y, z FROM tabela_diferente WHERE firula IN (SELECT firula FROM tabela_algo
    WHERE foo LIKE '%blah')
```

Agora imagine isso em 5, 10, 20 locais diferentes e você precisa modificar algo na query. Terá que modificar em todas as páginas que dependem dessa query. É trabalhoso e corre risco de esquecer algo, provocando bugs no sistema.

Nessa situação, poderia simplificar criando uma VIEW.

Com a view, os exemplos acima ficariam como:

```
#exemplo 1
SELECT x, y, z FROM tabela_qualquer WHERE id = 5 AND firula NOT IN (SELECT firula FROM tabela_view)

#exemplo 2
SELECT x, y, z FROM tabela_diferente WHERE firula IN (SELECT firula FROM tabela_view)
```

Para ter um entendimento mais profundo, consulte esse link: [O que são views em SQL? Quais vantagens e desvantagens em utilizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35413/o-que-s%c3%a3o-views-em-sql-quais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-em-utilizar)

<sub>Os exemplos acima são meramente didáticos.. dãhnn~~~</sub>