# Tornar dado do banco PostgreSQL visível ou não, sem apagar, é possível?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, modelagem

Possuo uma aplicação onde além de cadastrar e consultar clientes, ela permite emitir relatórios com as informações dos clientes, o problema é que muitos desses clientes já cadastrados não possuem mais importância para os relatórios atuais.

É possível tornar dados do banco inacessíveis sem excluí-los?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer isso na aplicação. Pode-se criar uma coluna com um *status* para indicar que a linha está desativada e não mostrar em lugar algum. Ou pode usar uma coluna existente que indique isso. Obviamente que se não tiver algum dado que possa ser usado como critério para decidir o que mostrar ou não, não tem jeito.

Também dá para [fazer uma *view*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35413/101), mas os acessos teriam que acessar pela *view*, se acessar fora dela, acessa os dados que não quer (dá para proibir o acesso fora dela).

Em tese poderia usar um índice condicional (parcial/filtrado), mas novamente, teria que acessar por ele para considerar o filtro, então uma forma é que todos índices sejam assim.

Normalmente isso deve ser planejado na solução como um todo. Ou seja, **não tem uma forma automática de resolver isto**.

Imagino que precise manter esses dados para garantir a integridade referencial, então qualquer solução de mover os dados para outro lugar não resolve.

Comment: É verdade, uma view é uma ótima opção

Answer (score 3):

Teria algumas possíveis soluções:

- Criar uma coluna para definir se o dados está visível ou não, dai filtrar por essa coluna.
- Criar uma tabela com os ids dos registros que devem ou não ser visíveis, e fazer um join nessa tabela ou `exists` se não forem muitos dados.
- Criar uma tabela de "backup" e mover para ela todos os dados que você não quer mais que sejam visíveis, removendo eles da tabela principal, mas sem excluí-los. Isso só funcionaria se não houver FK com outra tabela, que não permita excluir os registros.

São algumas ideias que podem resolver.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas na verdade, eu gostaria de saber se o próprio PostgreSQL possuiria uma forma nativa de ocultar dados DBA quisesse.