# View ou tabela temporária?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, view, tabela-temporária

Analisando um problema de código me deparei com abordagens diferentes para problemas semelhantes, onde um tem uma ***view*** para acesso a dados, e outro utiliza uma ***tabela temporária***.

Fui pesquisar e encontrei [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35413/64073) que trata especificamente de *views*. Fui lendo a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35420/64073) marcada como aceita e entendi mais sobre o que são e pra que servem as "*visões*", mas na última linha a minha dúvida ficou exposta.

> Ainda bem que não perguntou a diferença para usar uma tabela temporária

(*In*)Felizmente este é o meu ponto!!

- O que diferencia uma *view* de uma *tabela temporária*?
- Existe uma "fórmula" para descobrir quando usar uma ou outra?

Comment: A tabela temporária se "auto-exclui" ao final da conexão. A view não, é uma tabela virtual, seus resultados são de outra(s) tabela(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O texto jocoso ali é só porque seriam muitos assuntos :)

Na verdade elas nada têm a ver, são mecanismos muito diferentes para finalidades muito diferentes, com comprometimentos diferentes.

## *View*

A *view*, como pode ser visto lá, não é uma tabela de verdade (a não ser que ela seja materializada), é só uma forma de consultar algo de um jeito mais simples, possivelmente já fazendo uma desnormalização e oferecendo uma forma de acesso a certos dados sem entrar em outros para um usuário que você não quer expor tudo da(s) tabela(s) usadas no *view*. Os dados são sempre gerados a partir de tabelas reais existentes e o resultado específico fica disponível para esta consulta. Cada consulta nela pode gerar um resultado diferente sem fazer nada nela. Ela está disponível para consultas sempre, até que alguém mande remover. Algumas implementações permitem mudar seus dados refletindo na(s) tabela(s) original(ais). O custo só existe no processamento normal da consulta, que é virtualmente o mesmo que fizesse manualmente a consulta inscrita no modelo da *view*.

Para completeza, a *materialized view* cria a tabela física, mas sempre baseada em tabela(s) existente(s). Ela pode parecer mais com a tabela temporária, mas sempre (potencialmente) gera resultados diferentes em cada resultado e a tabela sempre está disponível para todos com o devido privilégio, até sua remoção. Há custo de espaço e processamento, mesmo não a usando diretamente. Já vi casos onde ela possa ser atualizada de forma independente podendo criar cenários, e depois ela volta ao estado original, mas não sei se foi feita para isto.

## Tabela temporária

A tabela temporária é física e só existe quando você manda criar. Ela costuma ser baseada em outra(s) tabelas, mas pode ser só algo vindo externamente (tecnicamente as *views* também podem, mas faz menos sentido). Se nada for mudado nela toda consulta aplicada gerará o mesmo resultado. Para mudar seus dados, assim como na sua criação, precisa de um código explícito que mande fazer. Normalmente ela fica disponível para aquela sessão, mas há como torná-la mais "permanente", ainda que não faça sentido. Ela é usada sob demanda e tem custo de espaço e processamento conforme a necessidade.

Como o nome diz ela serve para propósitos temporários, para algo que não pretende manter no sistema, e pode até fazer algo pouco relacionado com o resto da base, embora faça pouco sentido. Ela se compara um pouco mais com a visão materializada porque ambas são físicas. Mas as temporárias são para operações extras à parte da operação normal da base, as materializadas são otimizações ao acesso normal da base.

## Quando usar cada uma

É raro precisar de *materialized view*, quase sempre ela traz custos demais para compensar.

Quando compara a *view* simples com a tabela temporária fica fácil estabelecer onde deve ser usado. A *view* não permite mexer nela. Ela é um mecanismo de simplificação e otimização e é preferível sempre que isso se adéqua.

Já a tabela temporária tem mais custos e implicações, então sempre precisa de mais justificativa, tem que ter certo que outra solução não resolve. Praticamente nunca deve ser usada como uma *view*.  Ela deveria ser usada para criar dados novos, preparar dados para uso na base, criar cenários. Você faz o que bem entende naquele momento, dá para experimentar sem medo, ela não faz marte do seu modelo. Trate-a como um rascunho. Pensa nela como um treino, uma preparação para algo, uma simulação, algo independente da base.

Ela pode ser necessária em consultas muito complexas que dependa de alguma manipulação nos dados antes de serem usados.

A tabela temporária é uma tabela normal e pode fazer tudo com ela, inclusive criar índices.

DBAs tendem usar mais isso que desenvolvedores. Faz mais sentido em *procedures* ou processamentos complexos que só o DBA costuma fazer. Quem não faz consultas e processamentos mais "normais" faz menos sentido, mas pode fazer, especialmente em relatórios muito complexos.

Se o seu SGDB achar que deve ele pode criar uma tabela temporária para manipular melhor a *view*, mas isso é com ele, algo transparente para você.

A tabela temporária pode nunca ir para disco.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Porque escrever com as próprias palavras sempre é melhor... +1

Comment: Muito boa a explicação, clareou o que tinha de dúvida!!

Answer (score 4):

## Tabelas temporárias

O uso de uma tabela temporária no MySQL, permite realizar testes ou serviços em uma entidade transitória, sem se preocupar em limpar a sujeira depois.
**Ao desconectar-se do servidor, as tabelas temporárias são automaticamente descartadas.**

#### Quando é útil usar tabelas temporárias no MySQL

Algumas operações requerem que a existência de algumas informações seja curta — e que elas sejam removidas, quando não mais forem necessárias.
A parte da remoção pode ser feita automaticamente pelo MySQL.
Você não precisa se lembrar de apagar uma tabela, que não tem mais serventia, com o comando `DROP TABLE`.

Para isto, basta criar uma tabela, com a opção `TEMPORARY`, assim:

`CREATE TABLE TEMPORARY Nome_da_tabela`

#### Listar tabelas temporárias

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO\G`

---

## Views

**Uma View é um objeto que pertence a um banco de dados, definida baseada em declarações SELECT’s, retornando uma determinada visualização de dados de uma ou mais tabelas.** Esses objetos são chamados por vezes de “*virtual tables*”, formada a partir de outras tabelas que por sua vez são chamadas de “*based tables*” ou ainda outras Views. E alguns casos, **as Views são atualizáveis e podem ser alvos de declaração `INSERT, UPDATE e DELETE`**, que na verdade modificam sua “*based tables*”.

#### Os benefícios da utilização de Views (além dos já salientados)

Uma View pode ser utilizada, por exemplo, para retornar um valor baseado em um identificador de registro;
Pode ser utilizada para promover restrições em dados para aumentar a segurança dos mesmos e definir políticas de acesso em nível de tabela e coluna. Podem ser configurados para mostrar colunas diferentes para diferentes usuários do banco de dados;
Pode ser utilizada com um conjunto de tabelas que podem ser unidas a outros conjuntos de tabelas com a utilização de `JOIN’s` ou `UNION`.

#### Listar views

`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`

---

#### Referências e links

[Como criar tabelas temporárias no MySQL](https://elias.praciano.com/2015/04/como-criar-tabelas-temporarias-no-mysql/)

[MYSQL – Trabalhando com Views](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-trabalhando-com-views/8724)

[Listar todas Stored Procedures, Tables e Views SQL Server](http://www.codigomaster.com.br/banco-de-dados/listar-todas-stored-procedures-tables-e-views-sql-server)

[MySQL e tabelas temporárias](https://imasters.com.br/data/mysql-e-tabelas-temporarias)