# Trocando valores de coluna no MySql

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela MySQL com coordenadas, os nomes das colunas são **X** e **Y**. Agora eu quero trocar os valores da coluna nesta tabela, para que **X** se torne **Y** e **Y** se torne **X**. A solução mais aparente seria renomear as colunas, mas eu não quero fazer alterações na estrutura, pois não tenho necessariamente permissão para fazer isso.

Isso é possível com o **UPDATE** de alguma forma? **UPDATE SET X = Y, Y = X**, obviamente, não vai fazer o que eu quero.

A minha restrição de permissões, mencionada acima, efetivamente impede o uso de **ALTER TABLE** ou **outros comandos que alteram a estrutura da tabela / banco de dados**. **Renomear** colunas ou **adicionar** novas colunas infelizmente não são opções.

Se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Algumas possíveis possibilidades

Uma forma seria por tabela temporária: `TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Como criar uma tabela temporária:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table
SELECT X, Y FROM suatabela
```

Aplicando o `update`:

```
UPDATE suatabela
SET suatabela.X = temp_table.Y, suatabela.Y = temp_table.X
JOIN temp_table ON temp_table.ID = suatabela.ID
```

Outra forma (bem manual), seria importar para o excel, e "montar" as linhas para um `UPDATE`.

---

#### Importante

*Sempre faça backup do banco antes, e bloqueie o acesso, assim evita problemas maiores.*

*Não use `VIEW`, pois elas são apenas uma "visão", e alterando os dados, ela também será alterada.*

---

Mais sobre `TEMPORARY TABLE`: [View ou tabela temporária?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328509/view-ou-tabela-tempor%C3%A1ria)

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução seria juntar os dois valores em um e trabalhar com o `CONCAT`, `SUBSTR` e `LENGTH`.

```
UPDATE sua_tabela SET
  X = CONCAT(X, Y),
  Y = SUBSTR(X, 1, LENGTH(X) - LENGTH(Y)),
  X = SUBSTR(X, LENGTH(Y) + 1, LENGTH(X) - LENGTH(Y))
```

**Passo a Passo**

Suponhamos que temos os seguintes valores iniciais:

> `X` = `valor1` e `Y` = `valor2`

Primeiro passo seria juntar os dois valores em um:

> `X` = `valor1valor2` `Y` = `valor2`

Para pegamos o antigo valor de `X`, basta pegar o valor atual, substituir o valor de `Y` por `nada` e atribuir em `Y`:

> `X` = `valor1valor2` `Y` = `valor1`

Agora é só tirar de `X` o valor de `Y`:

> `X` = `valor2` `Y` = `valor1`