# UNION não está consolidando a SOMA entre 2 tabelas PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, union

Sou novo por aqui e estou buscando uma solução para este problema.
Tenho duas tabelas que somam valores de produção por hora de dois times distintos, porém, com o UNION ocorre a duplicação das linhas com a hora que contém valores.

Ex.:
Resultado da query A

[image: QueryA]

Resultado da query B

[image: Resultado da query B]

Resultado da query com UNION entre as duas tabelas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso que os valores das horas coincidentes sejam apresentados consolidados (somados).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   TO_char(a.acodatinc,'HH24') AS hora,
   SUM(ap.acoparvallan) AS valor_acordo
FROM acordo a
 INNER JOIN acordo_parcela ap on ap.acocod = a.acocod
 INNER JOIN usuario u on u.usucod = a.acousuinc
 INNER JOIN devedor d ON d.devcod = a.devcod
WHERE a.acodatinc::DATE = current_date-1
AND a.acoati = 0
AND ap.acoparati = 0
AND d.devsal > 0
AND ap.acoparnum = 1
AND a.carcod = 621
AND u.usunom NOT ILIKE '%1987%'
AND u.usunom NOT ILIKE '%105%'
AND u.usunom NOT ILIKE '%463%'
AND u.usunom NOT ILIKE '%1992%'
AND u.usunom NOT ILIKE '%2014%'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(a.acodatinc,'HH24')

 UNION 

SELECT
 x.hora_excecao::TEXT AS hora,
 SUM(x.valor) AS valor_acordo

FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT

 (SELECT
   CASE 
   WHEN x.carqueevecod = 3 THEN x.carresiteval
   END AS valor
   FROM carteira_resposta_item x
   WHERE x.carcod = cri.carcod
   AND x.devcod = cri.devcod
   AND x.carqueevecod = 3
   ORDER BY carresdat DESC LIMIT 1
 ) AS valor,

 (SELECT
   CASE 
   WHEN x.carqueevecod = 7 THEN x.carresiteint::TEXT
   END AS vencimento
   FROM carteira_resposta_item x
   WHERE x.carcod = cri.carcod
   AND x.devcod = cri.devcod
   AND x.carqueevecod = 7
   ORDER BY carresdat DESC LIMIT 1
 ) AS hora_excecao

 FROM carteira_questionario_evento cqe,
   carteira_questionario_evento_o cqeo,
   carteira_resposta_item cri,
   carteira_resposta cr,
   devedor d
 WHERE cqe.carqueevecod = cqeo.carqueevecod
 AND cri.carqueevecod = cqe.carqueevecod
 AND cqe.carcod = cri.carcod
 AND cr.carcod = cri.carcod
 AND cr.devcod = cri.devcod
 AND d.carcod = cri.carcod
 AND d.devcod = cri.devcod
 AND cri.carcod = 621
 AND  cri.carresdat = current_date-1
)x
GROUP BY x.hora_excecao
ORDER BY hora
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow. O `Union` une os resultados, não realiza a soma. Precisará utilizar o `SUM` ou relacionar as duas consultas e fazer a soma.  Tentou fazer em vez de duas consultas, apenas uma?

Comment: Olá Clark Maciel! Obrigado pela resposta! Não consegui unir a lógica em uma consulta somente. Acabam duplicando valores e outras ocorrências nos testes que fiz. Aí consegui os valores íntegros usando UNION, porém, sem conseguir somá-los. Tentei tratar a soma no PHP pra jogar num gráfico do Charts.js, mas, não tô evoluindo tbm…

Comment: Você sempre vai usar com esse campo `AND a.carcod = 621`? Ou pretende mudar esse valor em algum momento?

Comment: Ele sempre será fixo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `UNION` não deve ser utilizado para "consolidar soma", mas sim para unir conjuntos. Após unidos, poderá usar `Group By` para agrupar os resultados e a função `sum` para somar os campos desejados.
O ideal é buscar gerar uma consulta única que relacione as tabelas envolvidas e gere o resultado esperado através de uma tabela em comum que relacione as duas consultas, neste caso, observei que a tabela `devedor` existe em ambas as consultas, podendo tornar-se o elo de ligação entre as duas consultas.
Visto que você já possui as consultas que geram os resultados parciais, você pode criar duas visões(`acordo_parcela` e `acordo_carteira`), usar o **`UNION ALL`** para unir os itens dos conjuntos e somá-los.
O `Union` desconsidera tuplas iguais de tal forma que desconsideraria se existisse duas tuplas idênticas em cada conjunto, então no `Union` existiria apenas uma tupla como resultado, ação que tornaria o valor somado incorreto, na sua situação. No `union all` existirão as duas tuplas que, na sua situação, é o necessário, por tratar-se de conjuntos distintos onde os valores não devem ser suprimidos no caso da existência de coincidência dos registros de cada conjunto.

```
Select hora, sum(valor_acordo) as valor_total from (
  Select hora, valor_acordo from acordo_parcela
  Union All
  Select hora, valor_acordo from acordo_carteira
) acordos
group by hora
```

Esta é apenas uma forma de fazer com base em união (`union`) de resultados já obtidos por meio das suas consultas. Também pode utilizar `joins` para relacionar as visões/tabelas envolvidas e somar os valores dos campos de cada visão.

Para maiores detalhes sobre:

- **O uso de Joins**, consulte: [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join)
- **Diferença entre Union e Union All**, consulte: [Qual é a diferença entre UNION e UNION ALL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153496/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-union-e-union-all)
- **Views**, consulte: [O que são views em SQL? Quais vantagens e desvantagens em utilizar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35413/o-que-s%C3%A3o-views-em-sql-quais-vantagens-e-desvantagens-em-utilizar)